# Change Button Name="" and Form Action based on Select Option in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Hi I have form which contains three search criteria.

These search criteria are jobs, resume, recruitment consultant.
Based on the drop down, fields are updated accordingly.
Based on the select value I want to change the action on the form, and name of the submit button.  Problem is putting values with hyphen in option select makes jquery not work.

```
<form method="get" name="search" action="search-job-results?">
    <select class="homepage4" name="search_for" id="search_for">
        <option value="Jobs">Jobs</option>
        <option value="Resume">Resumes</option>
        <option value="Recruitment Consultant">Recruitment Consultants</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="searchjobbutton" id="search_submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Change the form action as per following

```
action="search-recruitment-consultant-results?"
action="search-resume-results?"
action="search-job-results?"
```

And the button name (NOT VALUE OR TEXT) as per following

```
name="searchrecruitmentconsultantbutton"
name="searchresumebutton"
name="searchjobbutton"
```

I put these in option values accordingly

```
search-recruitment-consultant-results?
search-resume-results?
search-job-results?
```

and then used

```
<select name="search_for" onchange="this.form.action=this.value;">
```

but putting hyphen in option values makes the jquery show/hide not work

Comment: Why change the name of the input? Why not have three inputs which show/hide based on the select value? --- Use `addEventListener('change' ...` and `setAttribute('name' ...`

Comment: i could do that, thanks for pointing out, perhaps i can have three forms nested under the show/hide and it could solve the problem.. let me try that

Comment: What javascript have you tried so far? Can you add it to the question?

Comment: I'd also recommend not putting JS inside HTML attributes like `onchange`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox your originial hint of putting the entire forms in show/hide divs complete with buttons solved the problem... sometimes the answer is so obvious!!!!

Comment: you can't create multiple forms for such a simple task.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, see i have use hyphen in option and it works properly.

```
<form method="get" name="search" id="form" action="search-job-results?">
<select class="homepage4" name="search_for" id="search_for">
    <option value="Jobs">Jobs</option>
    <option value="Resume">Resumes</option>
    <option value="Recruitment-Consultant">Recruitment Consultants</option>
 </form>
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#search_for").change(function(){
       if($(this).val()=='Jobs')
      {
        $("#form").attr("action",'search-job-results?');
        $("#search_submit").attr('name',"searchjobbutton");
      }
      else if($(this).val()=='Resume'){
        $("#form").attr("action",'search-resume-results?');
        $("#search_submit").attr('name',"searchresumebutton");
      }
      else if($(this).val()=='Recruitment-Consultant'){
        $("#form").attr("action",'search-recruitment-consultant-results?');
        $("#search_submit").attr('name',"searchrecruitmentconsultantbutton");
      }
    });
});
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help you

add id for your form 'formId'

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#search_for').change(function(){
        var cur = $(this);
        var search = cur.val();
        if(search == 'job'){
            $('#formId').attr('action', 'search-job-results?');
            $("search_submit").attr('name', 'searchjobbutton');
        } else if(search == 'Resume'){
            $('#formId').attr('action', 'search-resume-results?');
            $("search_submit").attr('name', 'searchresumebutton');
        }else if(search == 'Recruitment Consultant'){
            $('#formId').attr('action', 'search-recruitment-consultant-results?');
            $("search_submit").attr('name', 'searchrecruitmentconsultantbutton');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

Add data attribute with button name

only you need to add  - `onchange="$(this).parent().attr('action', $(this).val()); $('#search_submit').val($(this).find(':selected').data('name'));"` in the select

and `data-name=""` in the option

```
  <form method="get" name="search" action="search-job-results?">
<select class="homepage4" name="search_for" id="search_for" onchange="$(this).parent().attr('action', $(this).val()); $('#search_submit').val($(this).find(':selected').data('name'));">
    <option value="search-job-results?" data-name="searchjobbutton">Jobs</option>
    <option value="search-resume-results?" data-name="searchresumebutton">Resumes</option>
    <option value="search-recruitment-consultant-results?" data-name="searchrecruitmentconsultantbutton">Recruitment Consultants</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="searchjobbutton" id="search_submit" value="Submit">
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form method="get" name="search" action="search-job-results?">
    <select class="homepage4" name="search_for" id="search_for" onchange="$(this).parent().attr('action', $(this).val()); $('#search_submit').val($(this).find(':selected').data('name'));">
        <option value="search-job-results?" data-name="searchjobbutton">Jobs</option>
        <option value="search-resume-results?" data-name="searchresumebutton">Resumes</option>
        <option value="search-recruitment-consultant-results?" data-name="searchrecruitmentconsultantbutton">Recruitment Consultants</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="searchjobbutton" id="search_submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing multiple forms, just write one and use [.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) and [data-*](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) attribute which is used to create custom tags. Store the button names inside `<option data-name="button name">` then you can access this value with on change.

> The data-* attributes is used to store custom data private to the page or application.
>
> .change()
>    Bind an event handler to the "change" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

```js
$('#search_for').on('change', function () {
    $('form[name="search"]').attr('action', $(this).val()).find(':submit').attr('name', $(this).find(':selected').data('name'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="get" name="search" action="search-job-results?">
    <select class="homepage4" name="search_for" id="search_for">
        <option data-name="searchjobbutton" value="search-job-results?">Jobs</option>
        <option data-name="searchresumebutton" value="search-resume-results?">Resumes</option>
        <option data-name="searchrecruitmentconsultantbutton" value="search-recruitment-consultant-results?">Recruitment Consultants</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="searchjobbutton" id="search_submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```